# Appending XML Complex Elements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having trouble coming up with a scalable solution.  How can I append complex XML elements in SQL Server 2008?

For example, I have the following simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_audit (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [xml_file] [xml] NULL,
 );
```

Let's say I insert the following XML file:

```
<Input>
  <Element1 />
</Input>
```

I can append a second element by running the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE my_audit
SET xml_file.modify('insert element Element2 {""} as last into (/Input)[1]')
WHERE id = 1;
```

This works, and results in:

```
<Input>
  <Element1 />
  <Element2 />
</Input>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't scalable with more complex element types.  Consider appending this XML:

```
<Input>
  <Element3>
    <subElement1></subElement1>
  </Element3>
</Input>
```

Now what do I do?

These sort of calls are being made by a .net application which uses ADO to connect to the database (no this can't change).  If I wrote my own mapping library things could quickly get out of control.  That isn't a scalable solution.

Is there a TSQL command that I could just pass a VARCHAR variable "<Element3><subElement1></subElement1></Element3>" to append?  Maybe some other, better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned instead of hard coding elements, attributes, etc. I could setup another XML variable to handle every odd situation I could run into.

So my old SQL statement:

```
UPDATE my_audit
SET xml_file.modify('insert element Element2 {""} as last into (/Input)[1]')
WHERE id = 1;
```

becomes:

```
DECLARE @xmlAppend XML = '<Element2 />';

UPDATE my_audit
SET xml_file.modify('insert sql:variable("@xmlAppend") as last into (/Input)[1]')
WHERE id = 1;
```